# EF4 - Is there any way it can be made to support unique indexes

Tags: entity-framework-4

My primary key is a guid column and I would like to have a unique index on another column in the table. I read that EF4 doesn't do anything for unique indexes. My question is: Can I add to a partial class any code that would allow me to check for non-unique values before my data hits the database. Currently I'm using the following configuration:

Users Desktop <> wpf Datagrid <> Observable Collection <> EF4 <> SqlCe database.

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can do this, because to track value uniqueness entity framework requires all records from the table to be read into memory, or execute database query on each value change. It is performance-ineffective way and I think entity framework does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting unique key concept is definitely in scope for the next version of EF from what i have heard. But uniqueness will be enforced at the objectcontext level meaning what is currently tracked in the object context. This is the same concept for cascading delete which currently works in EF4. In cascade delete, EF only enforces cascade deletes to entities that is currently loaded in the objectcontext. It does not try to load everything from the database.