# How to make a field value unique in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, unique-key

I have a table with a key and another field named "CardId" .
Now I want to make CardId unique. I mean just unique value should be store in CardId.
How can I do it?
thanks

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as your data store?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176193/ef4-is-there-any-way-it-can-be-made-to-support-unique-indexes

Comment: And also here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614941/unique-keys-in-entity-framework-4

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use SQL Server, you can simply add an unique index to your table, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TableName] ON [dbo].[TableName] 
(
    [CardId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This will ensure that the column only allows unique values to be stored.

As far as I'm aware, the only way to specify a column as "unique" in EF4 is to flag it as the Entity Key (*please correct me if I'm wrong*), but this could lead to some confusion down the line as your Entity Key should ideally map to the primary key of your table.

Comment: +1 correct answer. Current EF version doesn't support unique keys at all but it is hopefully planned for the next major version: http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unique-key-constraints-in-entity-framework/